# Tense consistency with "think that....."

Tags: tense, past-tense

Can I say

> I **think** he was sick last night

or do I have to say

> I **thought** he was sick last night.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. It depends on when you are "thinking" it.

If you use *think* (present tense), it means that you are thinking now / in the **present** that he was sick last night.

If you use *thought* (past tense), it means that you were thinking in the **past** that he was sick last night.